# Security aspects about Module Twin in Azure IoT

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

my context involves IoT Hub and IoT edge device with custom IoT edge modules in Azure IoT.

I know that each edge module can have properties stored in IoT HUB on the cloud side called Module twin (JSON document) and also I know that module twin has the aim to handle and to propagate the changes to the edge side by connection encrypted with IoT HUB.

In terms of security about Module Twin I'd like to know 2 things:

- Where did module twin store at Edge side ?
- Is module twin encrypted at edge side ?

Thanks

Comment: [Isn't Microsoft coming back to you on this?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1352054/security-aspects-about-module-twin)

Comment: yes I'm waiting microsoft answer, but I thought that somebody faced this topic here. In any case I will update this question if I receive microsoft response.

Comment: using this code in c#  the module twin at Edge [side](https://i.imgur.com/EA9DSck.png)
 are updated at Module Identity [Twin](https://i.imgur.com/dWPQFUO.png)

Answer (score 1):

By using this reference [MSDOC](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-module-twins.md) and [MSDOC2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-query-language#c-example) `c# code` I am able to see Module Twin of Azure IoT in Module Identity Twin.

- AFAIK, The module twin is stored on the edge device in a JSON document.

**Code:-**

```c
 var connectionString = "HostName=sampath23sa454.azure-devices.net;SharedAc";
 var registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);

 var edgeDeviceId = "sampathp"; // Replace with the ID of your edge device
 var moduleId = "OPCPublisher"; // Replace with the ID of your module

 var query = registryManager.CreateQuery($"SELECT * FROM devices.modules WHERE deviceId = '{edgeDeviceId}' AND moduleId = '{moduleId}'", 1);
 while (query.HasMoreResults)
 {
     var page = await query.GetNextAsTwinAsync();
     foreach (var twin in page)
     {
         // Update twin properties and tags
         twin.Properties.Desired["sampleProperty"] = "newValue";

         twin.Tags = new TwinCollection();
         twin.Tags["location"] = "Building A";
         twin.Tags["temperature"] = "72F";

         // Update twin in the registry
         try
         {
             var updatedTwin = await registryManager.UpdateTwinAsync(twin.DeviceId, twin.ModuleId, twin, twin.ETag);
             Console.WriteLine("Twin updated successfully!");
             Console.WriteLine($"Device ID: {updatedTwin.DeviceId}");
             Console.WriteLine($"Module ID: {updatedTwin.ModuleId}");
             Console.WriteLine($"Desired properties: {updatedTwin.Properties.Desired.ToJson()}");
             Console.WriteLine($"Reported properties: {updatedTwin.Properties.Reported.ToJson()}");
             Console.WriteLine($"Tags: {updatedTwin.Tags.ToJson()}");
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             Console.WriteLine($"Error updating twin: {ex.Message}");
         }
     }
 }
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Additional References:-**

- [Monitor module twins - Azure IoT Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-monitor-module-twins?view=iotedge-1.4)
- [Tutorial - Synchronize device state from Azure IoT Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/tutorial-device-twins)

Comment: thanks for your demostration. But I'd like to understand well in terms of security, where module twin is stored at the Edge device side physically (e.g container, local blob storage or in other places) and also if the module twin data is encrypted at the Edge device side. Can you provide me these information ?

Comment: AFAIK, The module twin is encrypted at the edge side by a connection encrypted with IoT HUB and the module twin is stored on the edge device in a JSON [document](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-edge/how-to-access-host-storage-from-module.md). I couldn't find any information about the physical location of the module twin in the MSDOC documents.

Comment: Thanks again, we can have more details about it from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1352054/security-aspects-about-module-twin?comment=question

Comment: @Stefano  Yes, module state information is stored in the IoT Edge hub and twin data is encrypted using the device key (or) IoT hub connection.